# How do I count all the files at different subfolder using for loop

Tags: linux, find, wc

I want to know could I wc -l files are in subfolder.If only one file I can use code like below.

```
find ./calss{1..20}/ -name 'C1.student' | xargs wc -l
```

In fact, I have 20 folders , every folder contain C1.student to C50.student files.I want to use `wc` to count multiple files at different sub folders.

I try this code but got all 0, Did I miss something ? Thanks for your time.

```
for i in $(seq 1 50); do
find ./calss{1..20}/ -name 'C${i}.student' | xargs wc -l
done
```

Comment: The way you have formulated your pipelines with `xargs wc -l`, it seems as if you want to count the number of lines of text in each file, which is contrary to what you say in the title of your question. Can you confirm whether you want to count the number of files or the number of lines in the files, please?

Comment: Your requirements are poorly formulated. The title suggests you want a count of files while your attempt suggests you want a count of lines in those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In zsh (assuming the default value of `$IFS`, IFS-splitting used here to trim the whitespace around the number that some implementations of `wc` add):

```
for class (class<1-20>(Nn)) print $class: $(cat $class/C<1-50>.student | wc -l)
```

To get a report or the total number of lines in `.student` files per *class*. Or

```
wc -l class<1-20>/C<1-50>.student(n)
```

If you want to get the number of lines for each individual student in each class (and a `total` line if there's more than one file).

If the `.student` files may be deep in some subdirectories as your usage of `find` suggests might be the case:

```
wc -l class<1-20>/**/C<1-50>.student(n)
```

(note that `.student` files in hidden directories are not considered, add the `D` qualifier if you want them).

While `{1..5}` (an operator first introduced by the zsh shell and copied by a few others) expands unconditionally to `1` `2` `3` `4` `5`, `<1-5>` is a globbing operator and matches sequences of decimal digits that represent numbers 1 to 5, including `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` and `5` but also `01`, `0005`, etc. That one hasn't be copied by other shells yet.

The `n` glob qualifier is to order the list of matching files numerically.

If it's a count of lines of files of each student for all their classes you want, then:

```
typeset -A files=()
for f (class<1-20>/C<1-50>.student(N)) files[$f:r]+=$f$'\0'
for student (${(kn)files}) print $student: $(wc -l ${(0)files[$student]})
```

Comment: Thank you! It's work!!

Answer (score 0):

I read it as count number of files, ignoring that your code counts lines by using `wc -l`.

Try `sort | uniq -c` on the filenames,

```
find calss{1..20} -type f -name "C*.Student" -printf "%f\n" | sort | uniq -c
```

or to not choke on newline:

```
find calss{1..20} -type f -name "C*.Student" -printf "%f\0" | sort -z | uniq -zc | xargs -0n1
```

Output:

```
     20 C10.Student
     15 C11.Student
     10 C12.Student
     3 C13.Student
     7 C14.Student
     15 C15.Student
     48 C16.Student
     20 C17.Student
     17 C18.Student
     30 C19.Student
     18 C1.Student
     26 C20.Student
     29 C2.Student
     20 C3.Student
     1 C4.Student
     43 C5.Student
     20 C6.Student
     16 C7.Student
     50 C8.Student
     1 C9.Student
```